# Understanding Doctrine 2 new concepts especially command line tools.How to configure a project with downloaded tar package

Tags: php, command-line, configuration, doctrine-orm

I can say I am familiar with doctrine 1.2.X and I've used hibernate quite a while but i was surprised to be facing difficulties when trying out the Doctrine 2.
I find it confusing especially when it assumes one is using pear which am not.
basically i have simple basic questions on configurations
here is my project folder structure

```
doctrine2
bootstrap_doctrine.php
bootstrap.php
cli_config.php
--/entities
--/lib
----/Doctrine
------/Common
------/DBAL
------/ORM
------/Symfony
--/tools
-----doctrine
-----doctrine.bat
-----doctrine.php
```

my `bootstrap_doctrine.php` according to the manual looks like this

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;

require_once 'lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Setup.php';

$lib = __DIR__. "/lib/Doctrine";
$isDevMode = true;
\Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup::registerAutoloadDirectory($lib);

$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/entities"), true);

$conn = array(
    "driver"=>"pdo_mysql",
    "path"=>"127.0.0.1",
    "dbname"=>"doctrinetest",
    "user"=>"root",
    "password"=>"rootpass"
);

$entityManager = \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create($conn, $config);
```

my boostrap.php looks the same as the one on the doc page.now comes the cli_config.When it comes to that [tools doc](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/tools.html) suggests things that where already done in the bootstrap_doctrine but then there are other things that succeeded in confusing me.things such as the creation of the `$config` object and `$cli` `application` object.

So here are my questions.
**question 1** what exactly is the use of cli_config?
**question 2** to run command line functions should i use /tools/doctrine or /cli_config ?
**question 3** what are proxies for (same as proxies in spring/hibernate )?
**question 4** what represents hibernate DAO/Services in doctrine 2? repositories?

thanks for reading this and helping out.